# How can I open existing Chrome tabs on another PC with a single click?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, windows-8.1

At my desk, I have a Mac Mini that I use most of the time and a Windows 8.1 laptop hooked to an external monitor that I use only when moving work stations. Is there any way to open the Chrome tabs that are on my Mac on my Windows PC with a click of a button?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable tab syncing.

On Windows, Mac, Linux, or Chrome devices

- Go to the Chrome menu Chrome menu > Settings.
- Click Advanced sync settings and make sure the “Open Tabs” checkbox is selected. Note: To disable tab syncing, deselect the “Open Tabs” checkbox.

https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2591582?hl=en